# Observe changes for an object in Polymer JS

Tags: polymer

I have an element with a model object that I want to observe like so:

```
<polymer-element name="note-editor" attributes="noteTitle noteText noteSlug">
  <template>
    <input type="text" value="{{ model.title }}">
    <textarea value="{{ model.text }}"></textarea>
    <note-ajax-button url="/api/notes/" method="POST" model="{{model}}">Create</note-ajax-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('note-editor', {
      attached: function() {
        this.model = {
          title: this.noteTitle,
          text: this.noteText,
          slug: this.noteSlug
        }
      },
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I want to observe changes in the model but apparently it's not possible to use modelChanged callback in the element and neither in the note-ajax-button element. What is wrong? How can I do that?

I've tried observing the fields separately, but it's not clean at all. The state of the button element you see there should change depending on the model state, so I need to watch changes for the object, not the properties.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To observe paths in an object, you need to use an `observe` block:

```
Polymer('x-element', {
  observe: {
    'model.title': 'modelUpdated',
    'model.text': 'modelUpdated',
    'model.slug': 'modelUpdated'
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.model = {
      title: this.noteTitle,
      text: this.noteText,
      slug: this.noteSlug
    };
  },
  modelUpdated: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    var value = Path.get('model.title').getValueFrom(this);
    // newValue == value == this.model.title
  }
});
```

http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#observeblock

Comment: Thanks! That's what I've tried, but it's not possible to observe the the full object without specifying the paths? For example, when I add a new property, I'll have to add it to the observe block with that proposal, isn't it?

Comment: `Object.observe()` only allows you to observe top-level properties. For example if you change property `c` in `x = {a:{b:{c:'foo;}}}`, `o.O()` doesn't observe that change. `observe-js`, Polymer's library on top of `o.O()` adds support for observing deep changes to objects.

Comment: Is any sort of wild card supported for observing? Like 'model.*' or 'model[*].value'? This is especially useful when 'model' is an array.

Comment: Array/Object observing: https://github.com/polymer/observe-js .
Here is one trick, in Template-Repeat, trough the array of objects, if you add filter as: {{obj.property | modelUpdated}} if will react on each property change. http://plnkr.co/edit/zpiOIMOgDzdmaWpkS7Vd?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Or you can add an extra attribute to your model called for example 'refresh' (boolean) and each time you modify some of the internal values also modify it simply by setting refresh = !refresh, then you can observe just one attribute instead of many. This is a good case when your model include multiple nested attributes.

```
Polymer('x-element', {
  observe: {
    'model.refresh': 'modelUpdated'
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.model = {
      title: this.noteTitle,
      text: this.noteText,
      slug: this.noteSlug,
      refresh: false
    };
  },
  modelUpdated: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    var value = Path.get('model.title').getValueFrom(this);
  },
  buttonClicked: function(e) {
    this.model.title = 'Title';
    this.model.text = 'Text';
    this.model.slug = 'Slug';
    this.model.refresh = !this.model.refresh;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what I do in this situation is  use the * char to observe any property change in my array, here an example of my JSON object:

```
{
    "config": { 
        "myProperty":"configuraiont1",
        "options": [{"image": "" }, { "image": ""}]
     }
};
```

I create a method **_myFunctionChanged** and I pass as parameter **config.options.*** then every property inside the array **options** is observed inside the function _myFunctionChanged

```
Polymer({ 
 observers: ['_myFunctionChanged(config.options.*)'] 
});
```

You can use the same pattern with a object, instead to use an array like **config.options.** you can just observe **config.**