# Polymer changed watcher won't fire

Tags: javascript, polymer, addeventlistener, web-component

I am using a core-selector element within a custom element to manage selection of other custom elements.   I am currently adding an event listener for 'core-select' which then changes another object property.  For some reason that objects changed watcher does not fire when this change occurs.  Can someone explain why?

Code:

```
Polymer('custom-elem',{
     selected: {},
     created: function(){

     this.selected = {
        value: null,
        reflect: true
      }
      },
     ready: function(){
        this.addEventListener('core-select', function(e){
          if (e.detail.item.active != null){
            this.selected.value = e.detail.item.name;
            //logging displays the correct value
            console.log(this.selected.value);
          }
        });
      },
      selectedChanged: function(){
        //never fires
        console.log('working');
      }
});
```

I also attempted to implement the same code, but with an observer watching the core-selection selectedItem,selectedIndex,selectedModel property, which also never fired.

EDIT: Just implemented the same functionality using core-menu, which fires a function on-core-select.  Said function changes the selected.value property.  selectedChanged STILL does not get called.

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: the code attaches a listener to `this` and expects `this` to fire `core-select`. Is this intended?

Comment: not sure, my understanding is that a listener is added to this which is a parent of the child nodes where 'core-select' will be fired.  since the event should bubble up, this event listener should catch the childs 'core-select' event when fired, with a reference to that child. This does seem to work how I assume it will. If my understanding is completely wrong, please correct me.

Comment: this is my understanding as well. this question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073344/observe-changes-for-an-object-in-polymer-js. Basically, I think that, assuming that your event handler does get called, when you change a property on a watched object, Polymer does not watch for changes of properties. I am not completely sure about this though.

Comment: oh I see, I will try an observe block right now.  thanks!

Comment: That did the trick! gah knew it was simple and I was close.  Please post as an answer @akonsu!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that, assuming that your event handler does get called, when you change a property on a watched object, Polymer does not watch for changes of properties. You need to use an observer block:

```
observe: {
  'selected.value': 'selectedChanged'
},
```