# How do I observe sub-property changes in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

For this object:

```
obj = {
        a:'a value',
        b:'b value'
      }
```

I need to call a function whenever `a`'s or `b`'s value is changed.
I saw [Observe changes for an object in Polymer JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073344/observe-changes-for-an-object-in-polymer-js), but that solution is not working for me.

I tried unsuccessfully to add an observer like this:

```
 observers: [
    'abc(obj.*)' //abc is function which need to be called
 ]
```

and:

```
 observe: {
    'obj.a': 'abc'     // here I'm observing a's attribute
 },
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BvX25wJHJh7i2aeyVBks?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Plunker, the observer is not called after the changes to `obj.a` in your `ready()` callback because the subproperty was directly assigned, which does not automatically fire a change-event for observers (or data bindings) to see. Here's the corrected [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2ZqcDYnac14REZDBUATe?p=preview).

Polymer docs describe how to [observe subproperty changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#observing-path-changes):

> In order for Polymer to properly detect the sub-property change, the sub-property must be updated in one of the following two ways:
>
> - Via a [property binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#property-binding).
> - By calling [`set`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#set-path).

There's also a third way: by calling [`notifyPath`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#notify-path).

After making changes to `this.obj.a`, you can notify observers and update bindings by calling [`this.notifyPath('obj.a', this.obj.a)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-notifyPath):

```
this.obj.a = 100;
this.obj.a++;
this.notifyPath('obj.a', this.obj.a);
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      obj: {
        type: Object,
        value: () => ({a: 1, b: 2})
      }
    },
    observers: [
      '_objChanged(obj.a, obj.b)'
    ],
    _objChanged: function(a, b) {
      console.log('a', a, 'b', b);
    },
    _doNotifyPath: function() {
      this.obj.a++;
      this.obj.b++;
      this.notifyPath('obj.a', this.obj.a);
      this.notifyPath('obj.b', this.obj.b);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>obj.a = [[obj.a]]</div>
      <div>obj.b = [[obj.b]]</div>
      <button on-tap="_doNotifyPath">Notify Path</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you could combine the setting and notification with [`this.set('obj.a', 'new value')`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-set):

```
this.set('obj.a', this.obj.a + 1);
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      obj: {
        type: Object,
        value: () => ({a: 1, b: 2})
      }
    },
    observers: [
      '_objChanged(obj.a, obj.b)'
    ],
    _objChanged: function(a, b) {
      console.log('a', a, 'b', b);
    },
    _doSet: function() {
      this.set('obj.a', this.obj.a + 1);
      this.set('obj.b', this.obj.b + 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.3/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <div>obj.a = [[obj.a]]</div>
      <div>obj.b = [[obj.b]]</div>
      <button on-tap="_doSet">Set</button>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/LbBdPe?editors=1011)

Comment: thanx for your reply                                                                                                                         can you please tell me why its not calling observer automatically in my plunker code?!! and I have just written a demo code ,in my original code object have so many attribute and I can't call that function each time since each time one or more object may change ,and I need to call  observer only once!!

Comment: Is it possible to use wildcard like (obj.*) ??

Comment: I've updated the answer to explicitly state why the observer is not called in your Plunker.

Comment: In your comment, it seems you want the observer to fire only *once* (i.e., only the first change), which is currently not possible with the public APIs of Polymer. You'd have to implement your own mechanism (e.g., a flag) to ignore subsequent changes.

Comment: Your comment also indicates that you'd want to observe all subproperties of `obj` using a wildcard observer expression (`(obj.*)`). Yes, that's possible.  The observer would be called for any changes to `obj` (including its `.length` property).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I have one more confusion if in my obj object assume I have 10 attribute and each time any number of sub-property may change,so I can't write                                 this.notifyPath('obj.a', this.obj.a);
this.notifyPath('obj.b',this.obj.b); these 10 times,because it calls my change function many times, finally what I needed is any number of sub-property that may change but I need to call change function only once.!! is there any solution for this??